# UX Ideas > 20-20-20 Eye Strain Rule

Tags: user-behavior

I have a Web-Application which seeks to help Users reduce the Eye-Strain that they get from continuous sitting in from of Computer Screens.

URL: http://eyebreak.tk

The rule is simple and goes like:

> Every 20 minutes, if we look at 20 feet away for at-least 20 seconds, it will help reduce the Eye Strain.

Although the Idea is Good, but most of my end-users do not understand what this site is all about and leave it within few seconds (identified this statistics through Google Analytics).

What UX change may I need in order to convey the right Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the user what to do. Right now it simply looks like a statement:

> YOUR EYES NEED REST
>
> Every twenty minutes Look at something at least twenty feet away For
>   at least twenty seconds

The most important part is hidden in the bottom right of my screen:

> Next eye-rest in: 03:53 Keep this web-app + your sound open.
>
> It will remind you every 20 minutes to take an eye-rest.

Those are the only two things that the user needs to know. Remove everything else. Force the user to focus on the action.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve user interface but because you are asking for why user leave your site within few minutes is because, your site is not offering them anything at all other then a timer.

You need to add some ***content*** which will attract users to your site again and again...